# Django - how to create a new company and link it to the existing user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Good day all :)

I am new in Django world, Basically I have a three apps: `CustomUsers` , `Company` and `Team` with the following:

First a user creates an 'account' , then user create a new 'Company' and then a new'Team', my question is how to link the current user and the existing company to the new team ?

CustomUSer App:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="userimages/", null=True, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    member_of_company = models.ForeignKey("company.Company", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

and Company App

```
class Company(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to="logos/")
    website= models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
```

and finally team app:

```
class Team(models.Model):
     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    members = models.ManyToManyField("accounts.CustomUser", blank=True, related_name='team_members')
    company = models.ForeignKey("company.Company",
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                related_name='teams')
```

my questions are  how to link the new "team" with the existing company and user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where (and 'when') are you linking the new team to the others i.e. in a view, a function or as a default for the model?

Comment: i would like that team.company to be linked with the CustomUser.member_of_company, i think it should go through request.user and i don't know to do it.